# How can I plan an internal-external validation procedure per centre?

Tags: cross-validation

I would like to carry out an internal-external validation procedure as part of the development of a predictive score (ref : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5578404/#R14, Steyeberg, J of Clinical Epidemiology, 2016). 
I am in the process of writing the statistical analysis plan.
We have 4 centres including patients with an inclusion target of about 250 patients/centre (total of 1000 patients).

I would like to perform an internal-external cross validation per centre. 
As I only have 4 centres, do you think this is wise?

Is it possible to integrate bootstrap in the cross-validation of the 4 datasets by removing one centre each time?

I've looked at the trainControl function in the caret package, but I can't imagine how I can write that.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Full citation:

Steyerberg, Ewout W., and Frank E. Harrell. "Prediction models need appropriate internal, internal–external, and external validation." Journal of clinical epidemiology 69 (2016): 245-247.